# Can I close this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions

Seems to me that this question is asking for a list: [Which of Dumbledore's abilities make him the greatest wizard of the age?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106820/dumbledores-abilities-that-make-him-the-greatest-wizard-of-the-age)

Can this be closed?

Comment: You can *vote* to close it. I suspect you won't get much agreement.

Answer (score 10):

Lists aren't always a bad thing, especially when the list is finite, preferably fairly short, and restricted to a single universe or franchise.  This question seems to fall well within the limits of an acceptable list.  The list is short, certainly finite, absolutely limited to one universe/franchise, and there is an acceptable answer.

Comment: Agreed. Note that the OP is asking why he's considered the greatest wizard of all time. Although the highest rated answer is in the form of a list, it would have been equally acceptable to have a list of one if that one point answered the question.